# Retrieving position relative to a another on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google

I would like to SMS a URL with a call to the Google Maps API to visualize users' location relative to a location I choose, e.g.:

chosen location:
`https://www.google.com/maps/place/Boston,+MA/@42.3142647,-71.110369,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89e3652d0d3d311b:0x787cbf240162e8a0!8m2!3d42.3600825!4d-71.0588801`

I am quite sure I did it once but I forgot how that works...

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant the Google Static Maps API

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=47,19&size=600x600&markers=color:blue|label:A|48,20&markers=color:green|label:B|Budapest,Hungary&key=your-maps-api-key

You can use this link to display two (or more locations). You'll need to provide:

1. The center of the map (either latlng or an address) in the center attribute
2. Additonal locations like `markers=color:blue|label:A|48,20` Location in this case is the same as in #1: latlng or address. See the end of the highlighted string.
3. Your google maps api key